# led light strip not working

Tags: led

I have a 5m led light strip that does not light up. There are 2 wires at both ends of the light strip. At one end, i connected the wires to a driver and to an electrical point. As for the other end of the light strip, i kept the 2 wires separated. 
Do i need to join the 2 wire at the other end together. My preference is to keep the wires at the other end in case i decide to join it to another 5m strip. Tks

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume when you say "connected to a driver" that it's a DC LED strip. Possible problems:

1. The power supply (what you call the driver) could be broken. If it's a cheap one, that's not uncommon.
2. You could have the wires to the strip backwards; if it's DC, the polarity is important.
3. The wires to the strip could be broken.
4. The LEDs could be burnt out (unlikely unless you ran them at too high of a voltage).

You should not connect the wires at the far end together; that would short the power supply and could damage it.

A few things to try:

1. Check the polarity of the connection.
2. Try powering the strip at the far end.
3. If it's a 12V strip, you can test the power supply by hooking any auto bulb to it.
4. If it's a 12V strip, you can hook the strip to a car battery to see if it works.

My guess is that it's either polarity reversed or the power supply is bad.

Comment: Lights seem to be working after minor adjustments to the connection. Tks.